# Ektron PageHost - edit bar at the top not showing

Tags: asp.net, ektron

I have a basic page that has a PageHost:

`<PH:PageHost id="pageHost1" runat="server" DefaultPageID="38"/>`

but there is no bar showing up at the top of the page to show the edit controls etc.
This is missing:
[image]

What gives?

Answer (score 0):

There is some issue with cookies in ektron and the admin area.  Starting a new browser session solved this issue for me.